# Tridion CME can not load GetListSmartTargetInstances on https

Tags: 2013-sp1, smarttarget

When browsing to the Targeting tab in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 with SDL SmartTarget 2014 SP1 I get the following error, it only appears on HTTPS, the HTTP connection works fine. What could cause this error?

> /WebUI/Models/SmartTarget/Services.svc/GetListSmartTargetInstances
>   failed to execute. STATUS (404): Not Found
>
> [image]

Investigating the issue a bit further it turns out that the browser cannot load `https://server-name/WebUI/Models/SmartTarget/Services.svc/GetListSmartTargetInstances`

[image]

[image]

The WebUI/Models/SmartTarget is part of the SmartTarget extension for the CME. I configured the `%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\Models\SmartTarget\web.config` to allow HTTPS as documented in the [SDL SmartTarget 2014 SP1 documentation's "Configuring HTTPS" section](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-7450347C-F98B-4173-BA4B-D2462E9AD9C4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `%TRIDION_HOME%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Web.config` please could you try and set the `Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo` value to 127.0.0.1?

```
<add key="Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo" value="127.0.0.1:80"/>
```

If this works, then I believe its the IIS loopback check disallowing the request.

Comment: It is more secue if the loopback check is disabled. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861